# Scroll to refresh as button press iOS - non-UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, gesture, uirefreshcontrol

Sorry for the noob question but is there a way to use the "scroll to refresh" gesture as a button press?

Basically I have a simple app set up to demonstrate 1 aspect of a new project I am working on.  Currently it is set to update some data based on a UIButton press, but I think it would be slick to do it with a swipe down gesture.

Everything I've been reading seems to show the default scroll to refresh / UIRefreshControl is only for UITableView elements.

Is there a way to us this type of gesture to emulate a button press?

Comment: http://www.doubleencore.com/2014/05/ios-custom-pull-to-refresh/

Answer (score 0):

You can [try `SVPullToRefresh`](https://github.com/samvermette/SVPullToRefresh) which works on any `UIScrollView` subclass.

If you want to implement it yourself, you can use key-value observing to observe the scrollView's `contentOffset` property or check it in the `scrollViewDidScroll:` delegate method. From there, you can display the view you want above the scroll view's contents, and trigger whatever action you want based on the content offset.